# Do I have to worry about the refresh page on native application?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing my first native app with jquery mobile and cordova.
Because this it is not a web app I was wondering if I have to worry about the case where user reloads a page. I mean this won't happen in a native app right?
Because the point is that if it happens the app is completely broken!

thanks in advanced for support!

Comment: What do you mean refresh the page ? Refreshing it will only refresh the current html you are in

Comment: How do you "*refresh*" an app in your mind?

Comment: You best read this to understand the difference between Native and Hybrid Apps -- http://www.sitepoint.com/native-vs-hybrid-app-development/

Comment: ok... it is an hybrid app... said that, I know that in a native app there's no the "reload page" as in the browser, but I would like to know if anyway, for some reason that I don't know, I have to fix that. It means that I have to make this application works getting the parameters from the url.